# Symfony2 generating getters/setters

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, getter-setter

I am developing an application using Symfony2. The problem comes when trying to generate getters an setters for BalidatzeTaldea.php entity using `sudo php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Anotatzailea/AnotatzaileaBundle` The code for the entity is the following:

```
<?php

namespace Anotatzailea\AnotatzaileaBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 *
 *@ORM\Table(name="BalidatzeTaldea")
 *@ORM\Entity
 */
class BalidatzeTaldea
{
    /**
     * @var integer $BalTalId
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="BalTalId", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $BalTalId;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Erabiltzailea", mappedBy="BalidatzeTaldea")
     */
    protected $Erabiltzaileak;

    /**
     * @var integer $ErabGaitasuna
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ErabGaitasuna", type="integer")
     */
    private $ErabGaitasuna;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->Erabiltzaileak = new ArrayCollection();
    }

}
```

Getters/Setters for other entities in the Entity folder are generated correctly. What can I do? Thanks.

Comment: You really should not need to use sudo for this.  Think your directory permissions are probably messed up.  Delete the cache directory and try again as a regular user.  If all else fails, just add the getters/setters yourself.

Comment: Just tried that and does not work. Thanks. Any other idea? I think the error must be in the annotations somewhere but cant really determine where.

Comment: Try running `php app/console doctrine:mapping:info` to see if there are any errors in your annotations.

Comment: I tried that, the result is the next: Found 2 entities mapped in entity manager default. That means it does not know about the entity above cause there are 3 entities in total. How can i indicate default entity manager there is a third entity BalidatzeTaldea.php?

Comment: yes. Sure. Any idea what can it be?

Comment: All three of the entities are in the same bundle and live in the exact same Entity folder?

Comment: I thought maybe the fact that you had no space between *@ might have been the problem but it seems to work on my machine.  Post your code from one of the working entities up to and including the class XXX { line.  Got to be a typo somewhere.

Comment: Hi,this entity works properly:<?php
 
namespace Anotatzailea\AnotatzaileaBundle\Entity;
 
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
 
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Anotatzailea\AnotatzaileaBundle\Repository\RolaRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="Rola")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Rola implements RoleInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $Id;
 
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="Izena", type="string", length="255")
     */
    ...

Comment: Sorry for the mess, this is rola.php entity which works properly and implements RoleInterface. Thanks

Comment: Maybe check the file permissions?  I suppose it's barely possible that the console command can't read the file.  Very strange.  I would make a 4th very simple entity and see if mapping:info picks it up.

Comment: Permissions are set to 777 and with a 4th very simple class same problem. So what can it be?

Comment: You got me puzzled.  You are running in development mode with debug=true?  The entity file names match the entity class names (case sensitive)?  Your deleted the cache directory completely?  Not using network file shares or anything like that? Make sure you have a space between the * and the @ORM\Entity though I don't think it matters.

Comment: Hi, I am puzzled to. I really dont know what to do to solve the problem or where to look.

Answer (score 10):

I know this is old, but i just ran into this problem myself...

I had

```
/*
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;
```

And the setter/getter generation did not work. Changed it to

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;
```

And it worked! The extra `*` in the first line of the comment seems to change something. I also noticed it changed my IDE syntax highlighting.

From your code, it seems you had the two `*` in the first comment line, but if someone else stumbles on this, i hope it helps.

Comment: This has stumped me multiple times... even though I "know" it.

Comment: Well, this was unexpected.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

Delete the cache directory --> "app/cache" and try again

Comment: Cleaning cache with sudo -u www-data php app/console cache:clear can solve a lot of problems in symfony.